# How can we replace multiple match with only one word/phrase replace using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-ise

How can we replace multiple match with only one word/phrase replace using powershell

Below are the matches in the regex

> Grant access to Server1
>   Grant access to Server2
>   Grant access to Server3
>   Grant access to Server4

Need to replace all the results above with only one phrase below,

> Word of the day!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do those examples have any other text inline with them?

Comment: With `.*` you are set http://regex101.com/r/mZ1fA9/1

Comment: @Matt, yes there are also other text, I only show is the match from the regex.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: this is my current code. `/Grant access to \w+/g` but need only to replace this only with one phrase. not every matches. I'm using powershell

Comment: You are looking to match the entire lot ( all 4 lines?) `(Grant access to Server\d(\n)?){4}`

Comment: @Matt, not only 4.. I just only shows 4 possible matches.

Comment: @Matt, I tried your code and It works, thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what the OP is going for but you are looking to just match all lines with the following

```
Grant access to Server1
Grant access to Server2
Grant access to Server3
Grant access to Server4
```

You can use this as your pattern `(Grant access to Server\d+(\n)?){4}`. This will match the raw text "Grant access to Server" followed by at least one digit. In the event the last item is at the end of the string (last item wont have a newline) we include the optional `(\n)?` for newline. At the end the quatifier of {4} since the example only had 4 occurances. you could easily replace {4} with * as a greedy capture of all occurances *in sequence*.

So `(Grant access to Server\d+(\n)?)*` would also match:

```
Grant access to Server1
Grant access to Server3
Grant access to Server44325
Grant access to Server4
Grant access to Server44
Grant access to Server3
```